# Skylark - can a rule access the attributes of another rule from its label?

Tags: bazel

This question piggybacks [this github issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3414). However, I have ran into this issue in one other context.

#### Context

Within Bazel, there are two repository rules, maven_jar and maven_server.

```
maven_jar(name, artifact, repository, server, sha1)

maven_server(name, repository, settings)
```

The maven_jar rule's server attribute is a label pointing to some maven_server target.

Currently, whenever the server attribute is provided, the maven_jar rule errors out.

#### What I would like to accomplish

Within maven_jar's implementation function, I would like to access the maven_server's attributes. Specifically, I would like to do something along the lines of:

```
def _impl(rtx):
     settings_attr = rtx.attr.server.getSettings()

     # alternatively
     settings_attr = rtx.attr.server.getAttributes().settings
```

**Is this behavior supported? If not, any way I can approximate it?**

The server attribute is a label, so I'm not sure if one can obtain these values using its providers/aspects.

Comment: I can't speak for the maven rules (I don't use them). But I think the concept you're looking for is [Bazel Providers](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/rules.html#providers). This allows rules to get information from their dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately repository "rules" are more like macros and don't have providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repository rules are macros, so they do not have providers the same way "normal" rules do. Thus, if you specify a label attribute, it basically has to be a source file.

As settings.xml isn't supposed to be project-specific, I think it mgiht make more sense for `maven_jar` to use the users/system's settings.xml, as described in the [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html):

> There are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:
>
> - The Maven install: ${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml
> - A user’s install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml
>
> The former settings.xml are also called
>   global settings, the latter settings.xml are referred to as user
>   settings. If both files exists, their contents gets merged, with the
>   user-specific settings.xml being dominant.